# how to calculate the number of comparisons in linear search

Tags: algorithm, search

im trying to learn to calculate the number of compraisons in searches

```
    for ex Liner search(A,v)  (assume length[A]>0)

    i<-1
    while i<=length[A] and A[i]!=v
{
       do i <- i+1
}
    if i>length[A]
{
     then return NIL
}{

     else return i
}
```

how do i calculate it?

`i<=length[A]` should be N comparisons and maybe `A[i]!=v` too?

and what about `i>length[A]` is it count as 1 ?

a bit confused there hope you can help me out :D

self-learning from CLRS Introduction to Algorithms

Comment: You obviously know what a comparison is; good start.  We can't tell which comparisons you're supposed to count; that is part of the description in your textbook.

Comment: im using this linear search for example,lets say i want to count how many comparisons this algorithm does

how exactly i count them ?

Comment: Format your code, as is it is almost non sense.

Comment: well im trying to write in pesuo code like in the book sorry..

Answer (score 0):

You obviously know what a comparison is; good start.  We can't tell which comparisons you're supposed to count; that is part of the description in your textbook.  In general, we don't worry about *all* comparisons; rather, we're worried about how many loops we execute.  In this case, yes, the failing case (`v` not found) involves `N` loops (where `N` is len(A) ), one for each value in the list.

If `v` *is* in the list, then the loop count is the ordinal position of `v` in the list.  The mean value would be `(N+1)/2` if the `v` values are evenly distributed, but you didn't give us anything about the distribution.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: yep that helps me a bit i thought about (N+1) but where does the "/2" comes from ? is it the avg comparisons? 

lets say the values are random in the array(10,3,28,6...)

Comment: The `/2` is from series math: add all the indices and divide by the quantity; that gives you the mean.  For five elements, this is (1+2+3+4+5) / 2.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `v` is located at position `p < N`.

Then the number of comparisons is `2 * p + 1`, with `1` added for `i > length[A]` check at the end.

**Note** it is more common to count comparisons of values of `A`, and disregard index comparisons. This is because comparing values may be a lot more expensive, for example, because `A`’s type is a string. In this case you make exactly `p` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

For such problems, usually you consider the number of *key comparisons*, while the rest is considered neglectible overhead.

The rationale is that keys can be of various types, possibly with a high comparison cost, and we don't want to worry bout exact timing, just the number of is enough.

Said differently, the overhead is roughly proportional to the first-class operations, and we don't worry so much about the proportionality constant, leading to the asymptotic notation, O(f(N)).

FOr this linear search, the running time is O(M) where M is the position of the key in the array (or N if it is not there).